# Filter Picklist by 1 Value

Tags: filter, siebel, picklist

I have a question regarding SIEBEL CRM.

I have a created a picklist with below LOV.

| Value | Remark |
| --- | --- |
| Loan | Expense |
| Pay | Income |
| Sales | Income |
| Others | Income and Expense |

Now, I also have 2 applets Income and Expense. How do I filter the picklist for Incomes applet to only show values where Remark = Income, while the picklist in the Expense applet only show values for Remark = Expense ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Searchspec on Piclist or on Business Component wich based PickList